# Saleor dashboard CORS error during login (CORS blocked)

Tags: saleor

I am new to saleor.io which is an open-source platform for an e-commerce app. This saleor has three modules:

1. Saleor core (Django project, communicate with saleor store and saleor dashboard via graphql api's)
2. Saleor dashboard (Node project, containing javascript, typescript files)
3. Saleor Store (Node project, containing javascript, typescript files)

I am running these three modules and UI shows perfectly for each module. But when I try to login through the dashboard I got this CORS error:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `Nginx` you can write your location block for the `Django` Backend like this.

```
    location / {
        if ($http_origin ~* (http?://.*(:[0-9]+)?$)) {
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '$http_origin' always;
        }
```